# Insert Speed Deteriorates

Tags: t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

The basic problem is insert rate deteriorates as data is loaded.

- Disabled all indexes but PK
- Disabled FK constraints.
- Used LINQ to sort the data by the PK prior to inserting

But still have deteriorating insert speed.

During the load have a limited number of users.  So can't take down the PK.

The data is loaded in the order of the PK but that index still fragments.

Composite PK of Int, TinyInt, String.

Before the load rebuilt the index with a fill factor of 100%. The table has one other index that is disabled.

Now with 20,00 rows loaded into the table the PK index already has 4% fragmentation.  It continues to fragment and load speed deteriorates.  Check fragmentation with DBCC SHOWCONTIG ('docMVtext', 'PK_docMVtext')

- Pages Scanned................................: 155
- Extents Scanned..............................: 26
- Extent Switches..............................: 25
- Avg. Pages per Extent........................: 6.0
- Scan Density [Best Count:Actual Count].......: 76.92% [20:26]
- Logical Scan Fragmentation ..................: 4.52%
- Extent Scan Fragmentation ...................: 96.15%
- Avg. Bytes Free per Page.....................: 54.9
- Avg. Page Density (full).....................: 99.32%

The Extent Scan Fragmentation is high and maybe I should open a second question.

I don't think it is the varchar(600) value as part of the PK as there is a sister table docSVtext that only has PK on int tinyint and suffers from the same problem.

Created this database from another via backup restore.  Needed the same configuration tables but not the same data tables.  Deleted the data from the data tables and ran shrinkdb TRUNCATEONLY.

Using insert values (), (), () to load the values.

Thought that possibly the values  (), (), () was changing the order so changed the .NET to one insert per row and still got fragmentation on the PK even with data inserted by order of the PK.

Have triple checked that data is inserted in the order of the PK.

In the .NET app I am using LINQ to sort the data prior to the insert.  In debug I reviewed 40 and they were all sorted properly.

Even created a mirror table with an iden then the same three columns.  Used the same insert on that mirror table to validate the insert order.  When I select on the mirror table sorted by iden the data is in sorted order.  This is just a secondary test that I inserted the data sorted by the PK.

Below is the table definition.  (Yes I know in the first paragraph states no FK constraints and this shows FK constraint.  When I remove the FK contstraints no help on insert speed.)

```
USE [Gabe2a_ENCORE]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[docMVtext]    Script Date: 08/12/2012 20:13:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[docMVtext](
    [sID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fieldID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [value] [varchar](600) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_docMVtext] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [sID] ASC,
    [fieldID] ASC,
    [value] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[docMVtext]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_docMVtext_docFieldDef] FOREIGN KEY([fieldID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[docFieldDef] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[docMVtext] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_docMVtext_docFieldDef]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[docMVtext]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_docMVtext_docSVsys] FOREIGN KEY([sID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[docSVsys] ([sID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[docMVtext] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_docMVtext_docSVsys]
GO
```

What baffles me is that after this initial load I parse and index text to create a simple full text search index.  To load those tables I use the same strategy of sort in memory and insert in the order of the PK and I get zero fragmentation of the PK there.   I cannot figure what is different about the initial load to get this fragmentation on the PK.

I know people are not going to believe this but the major bottle neck was in the first table.

The first code below is 10x faster than the second with 300,000 rows in the table.  At 1.6 million rows the first is 30x faster.  Serves me right for using a sloppy @@identity in the first place.

```
SQLcmd.CommandText = commandText + ";  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() ";
sID = int.Parse((SQLcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()));


SQLcmd.CommandText = commandText;
rowsRet = SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (rowsRet == 1)
{
    commandText = "select @@identity from [docSVsys]";
    SQLcmd.CommandText = commandText;
    sID = int.Parse(SQLcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to bulk load data to initialize the table or do you bulk insert as part of normal table usage?

Comment: This is a dedicated data loading step.  Using insert values (),(),(). The program parses a text file one line at a time and then inserts rows associated with the line.  The input is too big to parse the whole input into memory.  I need a single line from the input file to succeed of fail as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a bulk insert for initialization, I would recomend droping all indexes on the table. By doing this you get the data into the server as quickly as possible. After that, apply the PK and non-clustered indexes when the data loading is completed. Sql server will be able to handle rearranging the data all at once instead of each time it reaches the fill factor for a given page.

Comment: There is another consumer app and have a few active users during the load phase.  Will drop the PK and test the loader app and consumer app on a test database.  It will take an hour for me to test it out.  Thanks.

Comment: I would also change your fill factor to be 60% because you have a varchar being part of the index. This will help reduce fragmentation but will in tern create more pages.

Comment: When I went to drop the PK it said will lose access to underlying table so that is not and option.  When the server is quite I will test various fill factors.

Comment: Yea it will lock the table while it's dropping the key. Depending on how much data is in there, it could take some time to complete.

Comment: As it turns out the major bottle neck was in a spot I did not expect. You did address the posted question.  Thanks